# Calculate square root with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

How can I calculate the square root of a number in Inno Setup?

Comment: Inno Setup is for installing software. Why would you need to calculate square root using it? It supports things that are done during software installation, and allows some extension with its scripting support. I see no reason it would calculate SQR, because there's no reason (at least that I can see) to do that with a software installer.

Comment: I have a simple serial check that uses Sqrt validation. I need to implement in Inno Setup routine validation.

Comment: Resolvido:   
recorre := 144;    
  for I := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      recorre := recorre / 2 + 144 / (2 * recorre);
    end;

Comment: You should add more information (the rest of the scripting code) and post it as an answer to the question. That's allowed here. :-) You can even accept it as the correct solution after a period of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After studying a bit the field of mathematics, could do the calculation.

```
//Sqtr calc
Function SqtrCalc(n : Single) : Single;
Var
  I: Integer;
  y: Single;
Begin
  y := n;  

  for I := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      y := y / 2 + n / (2 * y);
    end;

  Result := y;
End;
```